# Display a message if loop is empty

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates

I would like to display a message like "no content" using a "if" in my template.

I tried :

**views.py**

```
 {% for links in links_list %} 
    {% if links is None %}

    <p>No content</p>

     {% else %}

    <p>some content</p>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

It does not work, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the tag [for-empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) for this:

```
{% empty %}
```

For example:

```
{% for links in links_list %} 
 <p>some content</p>
  {% empty %}
   <p>No content</p>
{% endfor %}
```